# Cloning elements [div] [script] in Javascript

Tags: javascript, clonenode

I'm trying to clone a div in pure Javascript, however, cloneNode leads to duplicate ids (div_0). I would like to increment the id as div_1, div_2... and do the same to somevar = {'elem', 'div_1'}... Thanks

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
    <div id="div_0">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            somevar = {'elem', 'div_0'};
            //-->
        </script>
        <p>HELLO</p>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="cloning()">CLONE</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function cloning() {
        var container = document.getElementById('mydiv');
        var clone = document.getElementById('div_0').cloneNode(true);
        container.appendChild (clone);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean do the same in `somevar`?

Comment: basically is just a var that holds the value of the parent div. please, omit the name

Comment: You need to be more specific. Please show end result of the `somevar` object after a new div has been closed. Please do not assume that I know what you want. By the way, that syntax is invalid. It has to be a key:value or you have to make it an array.

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

`

```
function cloning() {
    var container = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    var clone = document.getElementById('div_0').cloneNode(true);
    clone.setAttribute('id','div_'+document.getElementById('mydiv').getElementsByTagName('div').length);
    container.appendChild (clone);
}
```

`

Comment: That does the job for the div id, now how could I increase the variable inside the `<script>` tag so it reads `somevar = {'elem', 'div_n'}`... where n is the increased number.

Answer (score 1):

Set `counter=0` and then increment after each `cloning` invocation with `counter++` and use `clone.id` and set it to `'div_' + counter`

Comment: This does not solve the OP's question for changing the contents of the script tag that was deep-cloned.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test this, but this might do the trick:

```
function cloning (e) {
    if (typeof e === 'string') {
        e = document.getElementById(e);
    }

    var clone = e.cloneNode(true),
        last_inc = cloning.last_inc || parseInt(e.id.match(/(\d+)$/)[0], 10);

    last_inc += 1;

    clone.id = 'div_' + last_inc;
    cloning.last_inc = last_inc;

    e.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

If you want to update a global variable somewhere, you can do `return { "elem" : "div_" + last_inc };` and assign the result of the function. Or instead of a return, you could explicitly make the assignment. I'd recommend the former.